# Trouble with subversion/cntlm/sources.list

Tags: linux, debian, svn

Linux/UNIX newbie here. Just started interning as a developer and trying to get my workstation setup in my Linux VM. I'm running LMDE MATE 32-bit in Oracle VirtualBox. I have cntlm installed, have cntlm.conf, apt.conf, sources.list set up (to the best of my knowledge) according to instructions.

I have to install Subversion. When I do

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

I get

```
E: Unable to locate package subversion
```

So I do `sudo apt-get update` which gives me `E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found`

Then I do `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` which gives me

```
E: unable to locate package apt-transport-https
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any advice?

UPDATE: Here is my sources.list

```
    deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest testing main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
deb https://svn.*******.com/svn/customer-information-system arempel main
deb https://svn.*******.com/svn/guest arempel main
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
```

Thanks!

Alex R

Answer (score 0):

After doing a `sudo apt-get update` to make sure you repo list is current, try `apt-cache search subversion` to verify that subversion is packaged under that name. The same can be done for any program to find what it is packaged as.

Comment: Just ran that search to no avail, it returned nothing. To make sure that the search worked, I ran apt-cache search firefox and the search returned proper results. What now?

Comment: Try `apt-cache search svn`

Comment: No results on that one either

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong in sources.list?

Comment: That is possible, update you question with your sources list?

Comment: Sure, its updated now